# How can I delete and create new csv file with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm storing data in CSV file, I want to remove CSV file content after test execution.

Or delete csv file and create it again before new test run.
Was using `tearDown` Thread Group and `BeanShell` Samper, and it does not work.

And If adding new csv again before execution, where should I write the script, cause test will not be run, untill system find needed csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I have a script which in the end produces customers to csv file, but before customers creation csv file is deleted. I used *setUp Thread Group* which is executed before other thread groups and in that setup group I used *BeanShell Sampler* with such code:

```
 import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

 String customers = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "\\customers.csv";

 try {

  File file = new File(customers);

  if (file.delete()) {
   System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Delete operation has failed!");
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

And it works as expected.

Comment: +1 for example. Although if the file has already been opened by any running thread, then it won't be possible to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

- `setUp thread Group` for creating new file

Check [this example](https://hellotestworld.com/2013/05/02/write-a-file-from-a-jmeter-script/) for file creation

- `teardown thread Group` for deleting the file

`new File("/path/to/your/file.csv").delete();`

Comment: to remove file should I add BeanShell Sampler with mentioned script  to teardown thread group or BeanShell PostProcessor? Cause both are not working. To add http response Im using same approach as described in a link you gave. Problem to remove it at the end(( 
http://take.ms/glxtE

Answer (score 0):

Just another BeanShell example, delete the csv of stored filename.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

String filename = "D://jmeter//"+vars.get("csvfilename")+".csv";
new File(filename).delete();
```